# Why does the compiler change the result of a linear programming solution? (GLPLK/GLPSOL)

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, glpk

Attempting to solve linear programming problems using *GLPLK's GLPSOL* we've come upon a snag, namely that in very specific cases, the results between *glpsol* executables created with different compilers are different.

The situation is that we have a problem with several valid solutions. To put it simply, we have a table where each row *(X)* can be assigned only one column *(Y)*, and viceversa. As such, all combinations that assign unique column/row pairs are valid.

Example, for a 2x2 table, these are valid:

```
 {(X0,Y0),(X1,Y1)}   {(X0,Y1),(X1,Y0)}
```

Now, the original glpsol binary we used under *windows*, returned the results in order, something like this:

```
 {(X0,Y0),(X1,Y1)...(Xn,Yn)}
```

We noticed an issue with the *Linux* binary, in that it returned the solution in a different order, something like this:

```
 {(X0,Y0),(Xn,Y1),(X1,Y2) ....}
```

Note that the order is not random, every execution follows the same pattern.

After much investigation I discovered that the issue lies in which compiler was used to create each binary. In our example above, the *Windows* binary was compiled using *Visual C++*, while the *Linux* binary used *GCC*.

I've verified this by recompiling the *Windows* binary using *GCC*, resulting in the same pattern. Compiling with *Borland* results in a different pattern.

So the question is, mainly, *why is this happening*?

I'm guessing it might be the result of how each compiler optimizes the binary, but I'm not sure, and my objective is to obtain the same results we had with the original executable (the one compiled with *Visual C++*) both for *Windows* and *Linux*. And I am suspecting cross-compiling with the *Visual C++* toolchain won't be an option.

**Note:** I managed to determine the compiler used by each binary by opening them as text and locating text strings within the executable referencing *Visual C++* and *GNU GCC* respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code. Could be that you're using compiler-specific ignorable features (`#pragma` etc.), or that your code relies on undefined behavior that is implemented differently from compiler to compiler.

Comment: I'm using the code from the GLPK distributions as-is, our purpose is to try and handle the binary as a "black box" we don't have to tinker much with.

I'm of course delving into it right now for lack of other options, I'll check and see if there are compiler-specific features, although I suspect the issue lies in the undefined behaviours you mention.

Comment: Clearly your algorithm is not written to guarantee the order of outputs.  The Standard library contains a number of non-stable sorting algorithms, these may certainly return different (but equivalently correct) orders when several items compare equal.  Or, you may have slightly different floating-point rounding on different platforms.

Comment: That's a possibility I'm looking into, since the source comes straight form the GNU download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions of the solver built with different compilers can take different paths during the optimization process which can result in the behavior you observe. Things that can affect this are: differences in floating-point semantics (possibly caused by [`-ffast-math`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath)), different implementations of sort (`qsort` is normally not a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)) - this is mentioned by Ben Voigt, different implementations of random number generators in standard libraries.

If both solutions are optimal, I wouldn't be too much concerned about this.

Comment: Unfortunately, for out application the order in which results are assigned is important. Thanks for the pointers, though.

Comment: You can always add a constraint to get specific ordering. However, this might increase solution times.

Comment: How would you go about adding such a constraint? The way we create the problem, variables are created in the appropriate priority order.

The GLPSOL problem was designed long ago by an external team, so all this is new to me.

As for increased solution times, won't be much of an issue given the use cases.

Comment: One possible way to ensure specific ordering is to require (a subset of) variable values in the solution to be sorted. Something like: s.t. c{i in I}: x[i] <= x[j]; This is the general idea, the details are problem-specific of course.